# Finding the spectral decomposition of a given $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to find the spectral decomposition of the following matrix:

$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
2 & 3 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So I found the eigenvalues which are $\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2=2, \lambda_3=4$ and the eigenvectors for them $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}, v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\3\\\end{pmatrix},v_3 =\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\\\end{pmatrix}$ correspondingly.
Now from what I understood, I should normalize the vectors above like that:

$$
q = \frac{v}{||v||}
$$
And calculate this: $\lambda_1q_1q_1^T+\lambda_2q_2q_2^T+\lambda_3q_3q_3^T$

However, when I do that the answer is not the matrix $A$ from above, but another one. Shouldn't the spectral decomposition be equal to the matrix ?

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I have checked the eigenvalues and vectors many times I can't find what's wrong with this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you :D

Comment: If you were decomposing a symmetric matrix, then the eigenvectors would (for distinct eigenvalues) be orthogonal.  However this matrix is not symmetric and the eigenvectors are not orthogonal.

Comment: @hardmath, thanks for answering. How am I suppose to find the spectral decomposition in that case then? Am I suppose to do some manipulation the matrix?

Comment: @Tannous If someone asked for a "spectral decomposition" of this matrix, they're probably referring to a decomposition of the form $A = PDP^{-1}$, i.e. the "usual" diagonalization of a matrix.

Comment: See for the terminology "eigendecomposition" meaning diagonalization ("sometimes spectral decomposition") in the [Wikipedia writeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you use: $$\lambda_1q_1q_1^T+\lambda_2q_2q_2^T+\lambda_3q_3q_3^T$$ is only true for a symmetric matrix. You can easily check that the result of such a calculation will always be a symmetric matrix by taking the transpose operator.

The general technique is to form the matrix with columns that are your eigenvectors:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}v_3&|& v_2&|&v_1\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&0\\1&3&1\\\end{pmatrix}$$
and calculate its inverse with your favorite method (for example Gauss elimination with pivoting).

In this case, you should get: $$P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{2}&0\\-\frac{1}{2}&-\frac{3}{2}&1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Then you will have $$A=P\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_3&0&0\\0&\lambda_2&0\\0&0&\lambda_1\\\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$$

Note that the order you use for the columns of P need to be the same as the order for the diagonal matrix.